Is it possible for one wing to stall due to icing while the other wing doesn't ice?
Is it possible for one wing to freeze with ice completely to the point of stalling, while the other wing is fine? Let's say the pilots made a mistake by forgetting to turn on anti-icing systems. Is there any possibility of this happening, and if so what kind of phenomenon would cause such a weird situation? I'll appreciate any explanation. Thanks in advance.

Not a duplicate of why would one wing stall before the other, since I'm asking specifically about icing here, not one-wing stalling.

It's not impossible I'd say, what about flying on the edge of the cloud with localized icing? if your plane is big enough you could have that kind of distance. And as you mentioned the icing system failing on just one wing is enough to do this too.

I have personal experience with a crisis on the CRJ200 program where the outer section of wing was not getting hot air, and the only warnings were random bleed leak warnings that were No Fault Found during ground ops testing. Finally someone investigated inside the LE and found the piccolo distribution tubes were rupturing at mid span. Airplanes went for extended periods without outboard wing anti-ice. How nobody crashed on an approach in icing conditions was a miracle.

@MichaelHall whether or not someone believes something is possible/true bears absolutely zero relevance when it comes to asking about it!  In fact,  the whole scientific research methodology is based upon you believing something and trying to prove it wrong or vice versa. Look up null hypothesis.

Point taken @MichaelHall but this is far from a question about unicorns. Any reasonable adult should understand that inquiring about something that is contrary to ones beliefs is very much valid, even more so than seeking affirmation to own ideas. Hence the downvoters are tragically wrong

Curiosity is enough!

@J.J., I understand and agree, but a voter's personal opinion on the quality of any given question is enough too!  ;)

Hey, what's with the 7 downvotes? Please tell me how to improve this post so that other users can benefit from it. I wish to contribute to this site more, so please tell me how to make my post better. I'll appreciate any suggestions or edits. Thanks in advance!

It's effectively impossible for one wing to be in meteorological icing conditions while the other isn't (at least for any meaningful length of time), but there are certainly several ways for an aircraft to wind up with one wing affected by ice while the other is not.
First and most likely, it's entirely possible for the anti-icing system on one wing to fail while the other is still working normally, which would potentially lead to an asymmetric ice buildup. There are many different types of anti-icing and de-icing systems*, so the specific failure modes depend on the details of the airplane in question. But in any case, each wing's ice management is a physically separate system, which means one can fail while the other doesn't. In a case like that, I'd expect a notification to show up on whatever error reporting system the airplane has -- ECAM or EICAS or just a dashboard light to indicate that something is wrong with the anti-icing without detailing what the problem is. Again, this depends on the details of the airplane in question and the details of what has broken. It's possible the failure may not be reported adequately to the pilots, depending on what exactly has happened.
Second, it's possible for deicing boots to make the ice crack off of one wing while the other wing doesn't shed its ice load fully. That could possibly cause one wing to have different flight characteristics from the other, making one wing more prone to stalling than the other, though I would expect the difference to be relatively minor and only impact the airplane as a whole if it was already trying to operate close to the stall speed. One would hope that in this case, the pilots would get a stall horn when the more stall-prone wing got close to its new, higher stall speed and take appropriate corrective actions, even if they don't understand why they're getting an early stall warning.
And third, natural ice buildup isn't totally symmetrical, so even in the absence of any deicing system activation, you can have the same situation as the boots happening naturally. The ice on one wing might form in such a way that most of it sloughs off under the usual aerodynamic forces and wing-flexing, while the other wing's buildup just happens to form in a way that doesn't lead to the ice departing on its own.
*There's a distinction between anti-icing systems like leading edge heat, which prevent ice from forming, versus de-icing systems like inflatable boots, which help remove ice after it has formed but don't prevent it from forming in the first place.

I dont think it is realistic that the airframe would accumulate ice only on one side. However, it is very possible that stalling due icing occurs first on one side while the other wing is still below the critical angle of attack. Actually this is most likely scenario to happen as heavy icing affects the airflow in very unpredictable ways.
It is also possible that when the wings are being de-iced the ice breaks unevenly. This is specially problem with so called de-icing boots which remove ice mechanically by inflating “airbags” that, when expanding, break the ice. If used too early there is not enough ice to crack but instead ice may form a cavity around the leading edge where the de-icing boot can expand without ever even touching the layer of ice. If this happens only on one side, the wings can have a very uneven distribution of ice. However, this is unlikely with modern turboprop aircraft which have automated de-icing systems and more sophisticated de-icing boot design. Jets use hot air to heat the leading edges and are not affected by this phenomenon.
The other scenario is that aircraft doesn’t have de-icing systems (or they are not used) and ice breaks away unevenly after the aircraft leaves the icing conditions. This can leave wings temporarily (which may be enough to cause very serious problems) unevenly iced.

Is asymmetric icing possible (and perhaps even realistic) when the sun is abeam and low in the sky, putting one wing in the shade?

@TobySpeight Maybe while parked, but not at flight speeds when the "wind" overwhelms the miniscule heating from a near-horizon sun onto a nearly horizontal surface.

'Technically' Yes, it is completely possible for one wing to freeze with ice and stall (somewhat like a wing drop) whilst the other wing is left without a hint of ice in a situation possibly where the heating system for our frozen wing hasn't been activated (and our 'unfrozen' wing's heating systems have been) due to pilot error and such and additionally, you can also have a system
malfunction.
